# VS Code environment variable similar to eclipse

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code

In eclipse N number maven tasks with VM arguments and specific environment variables can be maintained

each can be individually launched with given names

How do we achieve this in VS code, is there any extension or json files like runner or run with launch with ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your own tasks in vscode in the file `tasks.json`. There is a very good documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks).

As an example how to call a simple shell script:

```json
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run shell script",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "./script.sh"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to set environment variables you have to use the options:

```json
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run shell script",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "./script.sh",
      "options": {
        "env": {
            "PATH": anotherpath;${env:PATH}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: sounds interesting but I don't feel it is that sophisticated like eclipse GUI and tabs and grids, I can copy paste all environment variables one task to other in eclipse, I can duplicate a task etc...